# How to solve the problem of non-pingability of PC1 to PC2 or PC3 in the network diagram using the Javanetsim program, with this network configuration?

Tags: configuration, ping

I'm having a problem with a network diagram that I'm modeling with the Javanetsim program. I am using the following network configuration:

[image]

My problem is that I can't ping PC2 and PC3 from PC1. I have tried various settings and checks, but the problem remains.
I would like to know how to solve this problem and ping PC2 and PC3 from PC1 in this network configuration using Javanetsim program.
Error when pinging from pc to pc:

```
Unable to Resolve Destination MAC Address
```

Configuration:

```
Information for : R1                             Default Gateway : 10.0.120.1          
    Interface    IP Address                 Subnet Mask         Link Name 
    eth0           10.0.0.2                 255.255.255.0       pc1-TO-R1                                    
    eth1           10.0.120.2               255.255.255.0       R1-TO-H1
Information for : R2                             Default Gateway : 10.0.0.2            
    Interface    IP Address                 Subnet Mask         Link Name 
    eth0           10.0.0.9                 255.255.255.0       pc2-TO-R2                                    
    eth1          10.0.120.3               255.255.255.0       R2-TO-H1                                     
Information for : RЗ                             Default Gateway : 192.168.0.1         
    Interface    IP Address                 Subnet Mask         Link Name 
    eth0           10.0.120.1               255.255.255.0       H1-TO-RЗ                                     
    eth1           192.168.0.2              255.255.255.0       RЗ-TO-R4
Information for : R4                             Default Gateway : 192.168.1.1         
    Interface    IP Address                 Subnet Mask         Link Name 
    eth0           192.168.0.1              255.255.255.0       RЗ-TO-R4                                     
    eth1           192.168.1.2              255.255.255.0       R4-TO-R5
Information for : R5                             Default Gateway : 192.168.1.2         
    Interface    IP Address                 Subnet Mask         Link Name 
    eth0           192.168.1.1              255.255.255.0       R4-TO-R5                                     
    eth1           10.0.0.17                255.255.255.0       R5-TO-H2                                                                                                                                          
Information for : PC3                            Default Gateway : 10.0.0.17           
    Interface    IP Address                 Subnet Mask         Link Name 
    eth0           10.0.0.18                255.255.255.0       pc3-TO-H2                                    
Information for : PC2                            Default Gateway : 10.0.0.9            
    Interface    IP Address                 Subnet Mask         Link Name 
    eth0           10.0.0.10                255.255.255.0       pc2-TO-R2                                    
Information for : PC1                            Default Gateway : 10.0.0.2            
    Interface    IP Address                 Subnet Mask         Link Name 
    eth0           10.0.0.3                 255.255.255.0       pc1-TO-R1                                    
Information for : Hub2                             Default Gateway : Not Applicable      
    Interface    IP Address                 Subnet Mask         Link Name 
    eth0           Not Applicable           Not Applicable      pc3-TO-H2                                    
    eth1           Not Applicable           Not Applicable      R5-TO-H2                                     
Information for : Hub1                             Default Gateway : Not Applicable      
    Interface    IP Address                 Subnet Mask         Link Name 
    eth0           Not Applicable           Not Applicable      R1-TO-H1                                     
    eth1           Not Applicable           Not Applicable      H1-TO-RЗ                                     
    eth2           Not Applicable           Not Applicable      R2-TO-H1
```

R - router with two interfaces
I would be grateful for any help and advice!